# windows 7 WIFI file containing

Tags: wireless-networking

I recently replaced my laptop and I need to restore my WIFI directory containing my many username/password accounts. Are they stored in a file ?  Or where can I find them to transfer to my new computer , thanks

Comment: Like, passwords stored in your web browser? Or actual passwords for network connections?

Comment: Do you still have the old laptop? If so, just download Cain & Abel on it and dump your passwords.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the WEP/WPA passwords for your wireless network connections by doing the following:

1. Open the Network and Sharing Center from the Control Panel
2. Click **Manage wireless networks** in the left-hand menu
3. Right-click a connection and click **Properties**
4. Go to the **Security** tab
5. Check **Show characters** to reveal the network password